# US Permanent Resident and Citizen of Uzbekistan traveling to Canada do I need a visa?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, uzbek-citizens

I'm a citizen of Uzbekistan as well as a Permanent Resident of the US. I'm planning to travel to Canada for a short vacation but not sure if I need a tourist visa.

I am having a hard time trying to get in touch with Canadian consulate in NY since it doesn't respond visa inquires over the phone. I don't want to be stuck at the airport or sent back to the US if the visa is required.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Find out if you need a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp?country=Uzbekistan), citizens of Uzbekistan normally need need a visa to visit Canada.

However, I found a [page on the Help Centre](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=593&t=16) which says:

> As a U.S. Green Card holder, you do not need a temporary resident visa to travel to Canada. At the Canadian border, you will need to present your valid passport and Green Card.

Comment: Interesting to note that Canadian permanent residents on the other hand do need visas to visit the US

Answer (score 3):

According to the answer [on another question about visiting Canada](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30547/as-a-french-citizen-how-long-can-i-travel-through-canada), the Government of Canada provides a short questionnaire that helps you figuring if you need a visa and how long you are allowed to stay.

When filling the questionnaire with the information you provided, I could find that you are allowed to stay temporarily in Canada to visit without a visa. You can fill it yourself to have the result depending on your exact situation. But most likely, as a US resident, you are allowed to enter Canada without a visa.

Comment: Would the downvoter be kind enough to explain its vote?

Answer (score 2):

U.S. permanent residents don't need a visa to visit Canada.

Comment: @Vince: It directly answers the question. What are you talking about?

Comment: @user102008 It does answer the question but a reference helps.

Comment: Yup sorry that is a formatted message. As Karlson said, directly answering a question and writing a sourced and helpful answer are two different things. In particular, are you sure there is no exception to US residents to be allowed in Canada?

Answer (score 1):

A current answer to that question is available [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16). If you have a green card you don't need a visa. If you drive to Canada you only need to carry your green card, but if you fly you should also take your passport and should apply for an eTA before you go. The airline will use your passport information to get clearance to let you board (should they ever actually start doing this) and the eTA will provide the record of your passport they'll use to confirm this.