# UK no border stamp. How do I check if my visa information passed to immigration service?

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, turkish-airlines

I got a UK visa last month and visited London for a week. It was my first visit to the United Kingdom. I checked-in online when I was leaving the country and entered my visa number as an additional document. I was surprised after security checks in the airport, there is no passport control and I will not get a "leave stamp" in the passport.

How do I check if my visa information was passed to immigration service? Since I had an electronic check-in via a third-party airline company website, I can not be 100% sure that the company passed the information to theUK immigration services or their website works 100% correctly.

I already read the answer from here
[Left UK without passing through Immigration, why?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50676/left-uk-without-passing-through-immigration-why)

In order to avoid misunderstandings, I am not curious about WHY I do not have leave stamp, my question is: `WHERE` to check if my departure has been registered?

The proposed duplicate [How to fill out and apply for Subject Access Request (SAR)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88880/how-to-fill-out-and-apply-for-subject-access-request-sar) and its answer appears to be obsolete because "The Data Protection Act 1998 has been replaced by the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) and the Data Protection Act 2018. For the latest guidance on data protection law, please see our Guide to the GDPR."

Comment: @phoog My question is not about WHY i left without leave stamp. My question is WHERE do I check if my information is passed and my is registered. Its not a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, I've retracted my close vote.  I don't think it's possible to check, but it might be.  The airline's systems, though, surely work directly from their boarding pass records, and do not depend on how you checked in.  The information doesn't pass directly from the online check-in system, but rather from the boarding system into which your check-in data was passed by the third party.  They have to be sure not only that you checked in, but that you boarded the plane and were still on it when it left the country.  That's one reason why they scan boarding passes electronically.

Comment: It depends how I checked in.. What if (well I am a bit paranoic) I made a mistake while entering my visa number? In that case UK immigration service will think that I break the rules? They scan my boarding pass - yes, they do not scan my visa info, so possibly there might be a situation when passenger wants to edit that info?

Comment: They will match your record with your passport number.  That's why they scan passports electronically as well.  They did scan your passport electronically before you boarded the plane, didn't they?

Comment: @phoog no, they did not e-scan my passport. I entered via my boarding pass QR code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80120/discussion-between-phoog-and-neil-galiaskarov).

Comment: Didn't they check your passport when you passed through security? They certainly have the records there.

Comment: @xuq01 in my experience security checks are only concerned that the name on the ID matches the name on the boarding pass.  They don't scan the passport or look at the number. And airport security officers don't have access to immigration records.

Comment: @phoog Weird, I usually remember my passport being scanned somewhere in the security process. But my point is that there should be lots of records pointing to proper exit of the country.

Comment: @xuq01 in many countries the immigration authority inspects the passports of departing passengers, and that is sometimes done immediately before or after the security inspection, so it might seem like the same process. Perhaps that is what you're thinking of?  In any event, the UK immigration authority does not inspect passports of departing passengers.

Comment: @phoog No, I'm pretty sure it's the security staff. They probably just want to make sure that I am actually myself, though.

Comment: @xuq01 in what country?  The US TSA does check IDs, for example, but they do not record ID numbers, investigate immigration status, or even require a passport--you can use a US driver's license there.

Comment: @Giorgio the proposed duplicate question and its answer appear to be obsolete because "The Data Protection Act 1998 has been replaced by the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) and the Data Protection Act 2018. For the latest guidance on data protection law, please see our [Guide to the GDPR](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/)."

Comment: @phoog In most countries I've been too, of course including the US. IIRC that includes the UK. BTW, I am fairly sure that the TSA only accepts passports if it's an international flight (as they can tell from your boarding pass).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80132/discussion-between-phoog-and-xuq01).

Comment: @phoog Whether or not a question is a duplicate depends on the _question_ not on its answers. Regardless of whether the answers to the other question are now out of date, this question is still a duplicate. The answers to the other question should be updated.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The other *question* also needs to be updated.  But still, this question is not a duplicate, because this question is "how do I find out whether my departure was recorded," to which the answer perhaps is, or perhaps used to be, "file a subject access request,"  The other question is "how do I file a subject access request."

Comment: @xuq01 You don't Need a passport to leave the US if you have either a Green Card or NEXUS Card (the latter of which can also be used on ist own to fly to Canada)